# Simple way to make Apache ask for a password, unless from specified IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, password

Is there a simple way to set Apache directives that would:

1. Allow access without password from specified IP
2. Ask for password from any other IP

I'm looking for a way to achieve this by editing the directives, not by advanced configuration such as [setting up new handlers](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/security.pod.orig).

I've tried the configuration suggested by [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#satisfy) and [another forum post](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1402373) but it just seems to allow all access regardless of IP. The configuration I've tried is this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/restricted_htpasswd
Require valid-user
Allow from [IP]
Satisfy Any
```

Should this work? *(where [IP] is of course the actual IP)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this before, and it took forever to figure out. Here's how I did it:

```
# Requires a valid user unless 
# logged in from a specific IP address
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthName "Keep out"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/your/passwd/file"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Allow from 192.0.32.10 
Satisfy Any
```

What this will do is allow access if the user provides authentication OR is from the specified IP. The key is "satisfy any", which tells it that it must meet any of those conditions, not all of them. You can also specify an IP range, for example, `Allow from 192.0.0.0/16`.

Comment: After re-reading your question, it looks like this is very similar to what you originally posted. Perhaps the order has some affect on it?

Comment: Worked! Thanks! The key seems to have been the "Deny from all" directive.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 2):

Update: Give this a try...

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/restricted_htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from [IP]

Satisfy any
```

(Strike prior comments, misread question)

Comment: (Prior comments striked.) Thanks, it was the "Deny from all" that was missing from me.